# Named capture group in Notepad++ doesn't return captured value

Tags: regex, notepad++

I trying to flatten a sequence of lines using Notepad++.  I have a group of numbers

```
{
   {
      99999    0
   } nan "" "" Unknown Unknown -1 -1 nan nan 0 Unknown Unknown Unknown
}
```

that I want to be like

```
{
    {99999    0} nan "" "" Unknown Unknown -1 -1 nan nan 0 Unknown Unknown Unknown
}
```

My RegEx is `[{]\n.*(\d+).*(\d+)\n.*[}]` and replace string is `{$1  $2}`.  But when I replace, it ends up pulling the last digit from group 1 and I get

```
{
    {9    0} nan "" "" Unknown Unknown -1 -1 nan nan 0 Unknown Unknown Unknown
}
```

If I simplify the RegEx down to `(\d+).*(\d+)` it works as expected but at much finer granularity.  Notepad++ v7.4.2.  Is something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: FYI it's not named capturing group. It's numbered capturing group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a regex with a greedy operator, then your `.*` is capturing all your digits except the last one.

Make it lazy and it will work:

```
[{]\n.*?(\d+).*(\d+)\n.*[}]
       ^---- here
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/WT6wyF/1)**

Comment: OP even doesn't need `.*?` if they go for `\s*`

Comment: @revo I know, there are better regex for what he wants, I'm just fixing his

Answer (score 1):

@Federico found the reason for you but there is a much more faster way to do the same thing:

```
{\h*\R+\h*(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s*\}
```

Replace with:

```
{$1 $2\}
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pk7qgq/1)